# Use Media Queries to make main website responsive or redirect to a new one for mobile?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

I want to make a mobile friendly version of my website, but I have this dilemma.

What is better? Use `CSS3` **Media Queries** to make main website responsive or detect if user is using a mobile and **redirect** to a new one *(for example m.example.com)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really is depending upon what kind of website you are having. Your decision will not only affect the way your site is presenting, but also how you would deliver business strategies (if it's a commercial thing).

Responsive design will work just great with simple websites that doesn't really need too many detailed experiences. Company profiles, or landing pages will fit best with RWD.

Once you're building much more complicated application, you might need to re-think how the user will interact with even the tiniest part of it. Note that using RWD often require greedier resources compared to a dedicated mobile site. If you're dealing with e-commerce, social media, or some other mature applications, a mobile version is a way to go.